# What condition do I have set to have $x_j$ for $j=1,...,n$ to be non-negative?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

I have

$\sum_{j=1}^n q_{jj}(x_j-y_j)^2\le1$

What condition do I have set to have $x_j$ for $j=1,...,n$ to be non-negative?

The book I am reading says $\sqrt{q_{jj}}\ge1/y_j$ but why?

edit: center is also non-negative

Comment: This is not sufficient. For example $n=1$, $y_1=-1$, $q_{11}=0$ allows arbitrary $x_1$.

Comment: I think we need to assume that $q_{jj}>0\ \forall j$

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay That doesn't help. $n=1$, $y_1=-1$, $q_{1,1}=1$ still allows some negative $x_1$, for example $x_1=-1$

Comment: Yes, @HagenvonEitzen, a further sufficient condition has to be $y_j>0\ \forall j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this is the closure of an ellipsoid with center at $(y_1,\cdots,\ y_n)$ and having the half of length of the axes as $1/\sqrt{q_{jj}},\ j=1,\cdots,\ n$. So, to ensure that the $x_j$'s are all non-negative we must have the distance of the center from the origin along any of the coordinate axes greater than the  half-axis lengths in that direction, i.e. we must have $$y_j\ge  \frac{1}{\sqrt{q_{jj}}}\ \forall j$$ Of course here I am assuming that the length of the axes are positive.

Also, respecting the comment by Hagen von Eitzen, I should add the important condition that $y_j>0\ \forall j$.

Comment: thanks a lot. Could you please explain why half of the length of the axeas are $1/\sqrt{q_{jj}}$.

Comment: I guess you know that the equation $(x-x_0)^2/a^2+(y-y_0)^2/b^2=1$ represents an ellipse with center at $(x_0,y_0)$ with semi-major and semi-minor axes lengths as $a,b$ respectively, right? It is similar for this case also, only with more coordinates.